# How should a programmer get started with creating 2D Sprites?

Tags: 2d, sprites

I am a programmer. Given a sprite sheet, I can code game as per the requirements. But I do not know how to create these sprites. I use Cocos2D. And I do not know where to begin. I have never done anything art-related before. I am aware of TexturePacker. But it only packs already created sprites. So how do I get started with creating 2D sprites? Are there any dedicated softwares for this purpose? Main main concern is about creating assets for Retina Displays.

Comment: Also this served me well: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/creative/visual-arts/the-total-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-better-2d-game-art-r2959

Answer (score 10):

Pixel art is a complex field. Many people start with tiles and then expand to animated sprites.

A good tutorial I can recommend is ["So you want to be a Pixel Artist" by Tsugumo](http://www.yarrninja.com/pixeltutorial/).

You don't need any special software. Any raster-based image manipulation program will do - for a beginner even MSPaint.